# Как узнать и сравнить значение в поле input?

Tags: javascript

Как узнать и сравнить значение в поле input?

Например:
Есть input с именем q и со значением 5. Человек изменил 5 на 3 и ему выводится alert, то меньше 5 вводить нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" name="q" value="" onchange="changeQ(this)" />
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeQ (e) {
        if (e.value < 5) {
            alert("Меньше 5 в поле вводить нельзя");
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Оба варианта срабатывают только после перезагрузки страницы (в опере), так можно и РНР обойтись. А хотелось бы асинхронно... с помощью JS

Comment: Ну если это единственный `input` а форма сабмитится enter-ом, тогда можешь сделать `onkeyup="changeQ(this)"`

Comment: А если я в input введу строку? ;)

Comment: только не "e.value", а "e.target.value"

Comment: Нет, в данном случае функция `changeQ` в качестве аргумента `e` получает не `Event`, а `HTMLInput`. Как следствие у `HTMLInput` отсутсвует свойство `target` и будет ошибка.

Answer (score 1):

Накидал с использованием prototype( jquery я не люблю, на нативном было лениво )

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>
    <script>
        Event.observe(window,"load", function() {

            function initInputValidation(el) {
                el.observe("keyup", function(){
                    var info = $$(".info")[this.infoIndex];
                    var value = parseInt(this.value);
                    if(isNaN(value)) {
                        info.update("Введите число");
                        info.setStyle({
                            color:"red"
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        if(value < 5) {
                            info.update("меньше 5 вводить нельзя");
                            info.setStyle({
                                color:"red"
                            });
                        }
                        else {
                            info.update("ок");
                            info.setStyle({
                                color:"green"
                            });
                        }
                    }
                })
            }

            var q = document.getElementsByName("q");
            var qTotal = q.length;

            for(var i=0; i<qTotal; ++i) {
                q[i].infoIndex = i;
                initInputValidation(q[i]);
            }
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
        <input type="text" name="q" value="5">
        <span class="info" style="color:green">ok</span>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="q" value="5">
        <span class="info" style="color:green">ok</span>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Естественно таких инпутов может быть сколько душе угодно, не использовал alert т.к. это каменный век и, лично меня( я уверяю я в этом смысле не особенный ) они ужасно бесят

Answer (score 0):

Упрощенно (предполагаем есть единственный тэг input cо значением атрибута name равным some)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
    tagList = document.getElementsByName('some');
    if (tagList[0].value > 3)
        alert(">3");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input name="some" type="text" value="4" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Таких input-ов на странице несколько